# django rest framework dynamic url route

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, router, django-urls

I'm currently doing a small project in Django (2.2.5) and djangorestframework (3.10.3). I'm having a problem getting the view connected to the router. I'd really appreciate a second pair of eyes to help me try to figure out what is wrong

For the urls I have tried the following 2:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'<chatroom>', views.ChatRoomViewSet)
router.register(r'<str:chatroom>', views.ChatRoomViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and then added the router to urlpatterns.

The viewset is:

```
class ChatRoomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = ChatRoom.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = ChatRoomSerializer
    lookup_field = 'name'

    def get_viewset(self, request, name=None):
        name = self.kwargs.get('name', None)
        queryset = ChatRoom.objects.filter(name=name)
        return queryset
```

And the serializer is

```
class ChatRoomSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ChatRoom
        fields = ['url', 'name']
        lookup_field = 'name'
```

The model is:

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Is there something I obviously missed?

Comment: What's your current result? What's your expectation?

Comment: My current result when I run curl is 
curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -u user:password http://127.0.0.1:8000/first-room

Not Found: /first-room
[27/Sep/2019 04:21:40] "GET /first-room HTTP/1.1" 404 5038

I have several rooms saved including one with the name first-room I was expeting the details of that room to be returned as json

Comment: I didn't see your urls.py file on your question, just see the router so that might not have enough information for me or for other people to answer your question. That might be because you define router but not added it into your urlpattern so the url `127.0.0.1:8000/first-room` not found

Comment: if you see my comments under the first answer you will see the url set up

Comment: I updates the urls code snippte to include urlpatterns

Comment: I've just posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to add router urls in urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

if already declared the urls py then concat that list with router.urls list

```
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Comment: I already did that as I mentioned under the first code box path('', include(router.urls)), which is inside the urlpatterns = [] array

Answer (score 0):

There are some point I want to mention you first so that you can take a look:

- Seem like you're register 1 path with 1 view twice time (This won't cause your problem but just want to mention)
- You named your pathparams is `chatroom` but you use `name` instead
- `get_viewset` seem not right, to override the default queryset, you should use `get_queryset` method instead
- If you already use the param name on the param list like this `def get_viewset(self, request, name=None):` so that you don't have to use `self.kwargs` to get it anymore, python already handle that for you so just use `name` inside the function

After all, the code should look like this,

**URLs**

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'(?P<chatroom>.*)', views.ChatRoomViewSet)
```

**Viewset**

```py
class ChatRoomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = ChatRoom.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = ChatRoomSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk' # This will use to get the specific ChatRoom, you can remove it also

    def get_queryset(self, chatroom=None):
        # if you want request, you could use request = self.request
        # chatroom is the name you named on your path (<chatroom>)
        queryset = ChatRoom.objects.filter(name=chatroom)
        return queryset
```

Hope that can help you solve your problem!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it - but thanks! I overlooked that I had forgotten to add request and chatroom=none :)

Comment: @ChakoraChandra, just updated the answer. You could see that the url we register is different, rest framework using regex to matching url (it's not like `path`). So try that..

Comment: I just get the error
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "^(?P<chatroom>.*)/(?P<chatroom>[^/.]+)/$" is not a valid regular expression: redefinition of group name 'name' as group 2; was group 1 at position 18

Comment: That is a different story. I'm not sure that what you're trying to do with that but don't use one path param name twice on a path. `^(?P<chatroom>.*)/(?P<user_another_name>[^/.]+)/$`

Comment: I didn't I used the exact line you pasted above, django 2.2 changed the way django handles urls

Comment: I put exactly router.register(r'(?P<chatroom>.*)', views.ChatRoomViewSet)

Comment: Is `lookup_field` on your Viewset equal to this `chatroom`? It should be `pk` as default so that when you navigate to detailview then it still work fine with `pk`

Comment: I think that `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "^(?P<chatroom>.*)/(?P<chatroom>[^/.]+)/$"` error comes up because of the `lookup_field` is `chatroom`. Django will automatically register a path based on that field value so that might led you got that error

Answer (score 0):

Replace `get_viewset` by `get_queryset` in your viewset. Also, you either declare `queryset` attribute in a viewset or implement `get_queryset` function.